# How to make XNA movable mask on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I have two textures: background and mask. I need to make output that mask defines what is revealed form background. Very important part is that mask needs to be less size then background I will move it in runtime revealing parts of background.

[image]

Project is on WP7 so there is limited [`BlendState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.blendstate.aspx) manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built in **AlphaTestEffect** with the **Stencil Buffer** to achieve the masking you are after.

The steps are:

1. Clear the stencil buffer
2. Draw your mask to the stencil buffer using AlphaTestEffect so only non-transparent pixels are drawn.
3. Draw your image using stencil buffer masking.

The Crappy Coding article [Texture Modification using Render Targets, with some Stencil Buffer Action](http://www.crappycoding.com/2010/08/texture-modification-using-render-targets-with-some-stencil-buffer-action/) shows how to do this and has working sample code.